# Wordpress shortcodes don't work in one theme

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have developed a wordpress plugin that uses shortcodes.
The problem is that it don't work in this theme:

http://judopassion.com/wordpress/?p=274

I have tried to add this line in functions.php but don't work anyway:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

What is wrong? Have I to enable shortcode api on the theme? how?
Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to do? Register a shortcode?

Comment: sorry I have resolved with do_shortcode();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `get_the_content()` method and not `the_content();`

So I have to modify in;

```
do_shortcode(get_the_content());
```